# Checking BackgroundAccessStatus throws "The process has no application identity" exception

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, background-process

I am attempting to register a [UWP background task trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task) from a C# console app (.NET Core) on Windows 10 so I can [monitor notification events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener#background-task-for-notification-addeddismissed). However, when I try to request permission to run background tasks, I get an error saying "The process has no application identity".

```
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main()
        {
            BackgroundAccessStatus hasAccess = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            if (hasAccess == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedBySystemPolicy
                || hasAccess == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser
                || hasAccess == BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access denied for background task");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in ConsoleApp.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ConsoleApp.dll but was not handled in user code
The process has no application identity. (0x80073D57)
```

How do I give my application an identity so I can register background tasks?

Comment: I don't think you can. You'll have to use regular .NET threading models

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm registering a background task so I can [monitor UWP notification events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener#background-task-for-notification-addeddismissed). I don't know if this can be done with traditional .NET threads. I've edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: have you [created a Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) for the .net core application?